# Git clones repository with CRLF even though I have core.autocrlf=false

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

When I clone a repository that uses LF line endings using msysgit on Windows, the checked out files have somehow the CRLF line endings even though my `core.autocrlf` is set to `false`. Why is that?

Example:

```
> git config core.autocrlf
false

> git clone https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli.git wp-cli
```

The checked out files have CRLF line endings even though they have LF in the repository itself.

Comment: Related information: [it is possible](https://kristofferahl.tumblr.com/post/23674906364/git-clone-autocrlf) to pass `--config core.autocrlf=somevalue` to `git clone`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a .gitattributes file in the project

```
# Auto detect text files and perform EOL normalization
* text=auto
```

This has higher priority than core.autocrlf.

See http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Answer (score 1):

Aha, `.gitattributes` also influences this, and [there is such file](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/master/.gitattributes) in the wp-cli repository.